# Office 2007 deploy - gpo script on windows startup does not wait for its termination, instead winlogon appears immediately

Tags: installation, microsoft-office

I have to deploy Office 2007 to a bunch of clients. I followed these instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179134%28v=office.12%29.aspx

The method is to create a script (a very simple bat file) and create a gpo that runs it at windows startup. Clients on which I install Office are all with 32 bit OS. The script is:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto DeployOffice) else (goto End)

:DeployOffice
start /WAIT \\biokolorsrv01\Software\SoftwareDistributionPoint\Office_2007_Ent\setup.exe /config \\biokolorsrv01\Software\SoftwareDistributionPoint\Office_2007_Ent\Enterprise.WW\config.xml

:End
```

I have created a GPO with startup script that points to the above mentioned bat on the computer settings section. In the user settings of the GPO there's another very little script that copies old signatures to the correct folder "Signatures" from folder "Firme Elettroniche" (I'm italian so Office 2003 used this name for signatures). This GPO is linked to the OU that contains all my clients and users. I've created a security group in Active Directory whose members are those Computers and Users to which I will install Office 2007 to. The GPO applies only to members of that group (security section of GPO).

Issue: the script does not run in foreground or better the wait switch is not considered. So the setup starts and comes up immediately the logon window as if I had omitted the /WAIT switch. Then the setup goes on for a while but then stops (I've also set the max script execution time to 0 in the gpo to allow the script to run until it fineshes). What's wrong with my deploy setup?? Is it perhaps better to make the scripts to run on user logon instead on windows startup?

Your help is very appreciated. Thank you.
Francesco B.